# Is there any way to convert a Context(ctx) object to be subscriptable?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I'm a beginner to python and am trying to make a bot. Here's where I want to use ctx.

```
@bot.command(aliases = actions)
async def call(ctx, *, member: discord.Member):  

  response = ctx.author.name + " is " + ctx + "ing " + member.name + "!"
  giflink = random.choice(action(("anime" + ctx)))
  gif = giflink.replace("'", ' ').replace(",", ' ')

  embed = discord.Embed(title = response, color = discord.Color.blue())
  embed.set_image(url = gif)
  await ctx.send(embed = embed)
```

My prefix is '.' ; So I want to use .'action' in discord and use 'action' as a string in the response.
I've tried str(ctx), I don't know any other ways to convert to string.

Comment: You can grab `ctx.invoked_with` to see what command name was used - https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Context.invoked_with

Comment: @haliphax Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
@bot.command(aliases = actions)
async def call(ctx:str, *, member: discord.Member):  #added str here

  response = ctx.author.name + " is " + ctx + "ing " + member.name + "!"
  giflink = random.choice(action(("anime" + ctx)))
  gif = giflink.replace("'", ' ').replace(",", ' ')

  embed = discord.Embed(title = response, color = discord.Color.blue())
  embed.set_image(url = gif)
  await ctx.send(embed = embed)
```

Comment: At least give a brief explanation